# Bitbucket Pipeline to Heroku failing

Tags: node.js, npm, heroku, bitbucket-pipelines

I've trying to create a Pipeline from BitBucket that deploys Master branch into Heroku. What have I done wrong?!
For the template, I have used https://medium.com/finnovate-io/deploy-code-to-multiple-heroku-environments-with-bitbucket-pipeline-3d64c86887d8 which seems to be the recommended template.

Please - any thoughts/help gratefully received :)

Pipeline file:

```html
clone:
  depth: full
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - node
        script: 
          # This gets executed on every push by a developer
          - npm install
          - npm test
  branches:
    development:
      - step:
          name: 'Deployment to staging'
          deployment: staging
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            # This gets executed when merging a PR to dev branch
            - npm install
            - npm test
# We need to compile code, code is typically stored in
            # a destination directory.  
            # Replace with your own command
            #- npm run build:staging
# We need to commit build in the image before pushing
            - git add -A
            - git config --global user.email "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
            - git config --global user.name "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
            - git commit -m "staging build"
# Finally, we push to Heroku
            - git push -f https://heroku:XXXXXXXXXXXX@git.heroku.com/XXXXXXXXXXXX.dev.git development:master
    master:
      - step:
          name: 'Deployment to live'
          deployment: production
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            # This gets executed when merging a PR to master branch
            - npm --loglevel=error install
            - npm-check-updates -u
            - npm test
            - npm run build:master
            - git add -A
            - git config --global user.email "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
            - git config --global user.name "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
            - git commit -m "production build"
            - git push -f https://heroku:XXXXXXXXXXXX@git.heroku.com/XXXXXXXXXXXX.git master
```

Output:

```html
+ npm --loglevel=error install
> node-addon-api@3.2.1 install /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/sharp/node_modules/node-addon-api
> node-gyp rebuild
gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/sharp/node_modules/node-addon-api) while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/bin/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:355:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 5.10.101
gyp ERR! command "/bin/versions/node/v4.2.1/bin/node" "/bin/versions/node/v4.2.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/sharp/node_modules/node-addon-api
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
> es5-ext@0.10.62 postinstall /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/undertaker/node_modules/es6-weak-map/node_modules/es5-ext
>  node -e "try{require('./_postinstall')}catch(e){}" || exit 0
> es5-ext@0.10.62 postinstall /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-cli/node_modules/semver-greatest-satisfied-range/node_modules/sver-compat/node_modules/es6-iterator/node_modules/es5-ext
>  node -e "try{require('./_postinstall')}catch(e){}" || exit 0
> es5-ext@0.10.62 postinstall /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-cli/node_modules/semver-greatest-satisfied-range/node_modules/sver-compat/node_modules/es6-symbol/node_modules/d/node_modules/es5-ext
>  node -e "try{require('./_postinstall')}catch(e){}" || exit 0
npm ERR! Linux 5.10.101
npm ERR! argv "/bin/versions/node/v4.2.1/bin/node" "/bin/versions/node/v4.2.1/bin/npm" "--loglevel=error" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! node-addon-api@3.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-addon-api@3.2.1 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-addon-api package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-addon-api
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/npm-debug.log
```